# Are these 2 expressions using quotation and list the same when evalulating expressions?

Tags: scheme

Are these 2 expressions using quotation and list the same when evaluating the expression such as a derivative?

The intrepreter outputs the same values for both:

```
(define a '(+ 3 4))
(define b (list '+ 3 4))

a
b

(car a)
(car b)
```

Output:

```
=> (+ 3 4)

=> (+ 3 4)
+
+
```

Answer (score 2):

For these expressions:

```
(define a '(+ 3 4))
(define b (list '+ 3 4))
```

Do they have the same value? yes:

```
(equal? a b)
=> #t
```

Do they refer to the same object? no:

```
(eq? a b)
=> #f
```

I guess that you want to somehow process the lists (say, for calculating a derivative). It doesn't matter how you created the lists as long as you're only interested in treating them as lists of symbols, and you can safely switch back and forth between either representation. It'd be different if you were to treat the operators as actual *procedures*, these are different things:

```
(define a '(+ 3 4))
(define b (list + 3 4)) ; quote was removed
(equal? a b)
=> #f
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example:

```
(define a '(+ 3 4))
(define b (list '+ 3 4))
(define c '(+ 3 4))
```

Here `a` will point to an immutable* list `(+ 3 4)`. `b` will point to a list whose elements are the same as `a` but it's produced when that statement is evaluated (`a` can exist before the program runs since it's a constant and for a compiled program the order and how it gets produced is not important). In `b` you are guaranteed that all the `cons` cells are newly created and unique. Thus `(equal? a b) ; ==>#t` while `(eq? a b) ; ==> #f`.

The output of `(eq? a c)` is undefined. Some Scheme implementations will create a new immutable list while others will point to the same list created earlier because they are both immutable according to the spec.

*Immutable by the specifications in the Scheme standard but this is seldom enforced so many implementations lets you alter immutable data with undefined behavior as consequence.